# Optimize PostgreSQL query used by a function in plpgsql (or find an alternative)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, function, plpgsql

I have a function in pl/pgsql which returns the mvp of the home and away team of a specific football match, given the matchID. 
 Basically, for every match (a single row in the table 'match'), there are 2 formation (one for each team, 'home_squad' and 'away_squad') which refer to another table ('squad') containing the 11 IDs for the players of the roster. So for a team i must check all of the ratings (attribute 'overall_rating') given to every player of the formation (in 'playerAttribute', which can contain multiple rows for a given playerID) and consider the rating whose date is closer (in the past) from the date of the match. 
 The player who has the highest rating counts as the mvp.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION top_away_player(matchId VARCHAR) RETURNS TABLE(name VARCHAR, rating ATTRIBUTE)
AS $$
 DECLARE
  top_row record;
  temp_row record;
  attr VARCHAR;
 BEGIN

  FOR counter in 1..11 LOOP

   attr := CONCAT('away.player', counter::VARCHAR, '_id');

   EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || attr || ' AS id, play.overall_rating AS rating, play.attribute_date AS date
   FROM match
   JOIN squad AS away ON match.away_squad = away.squadId
   JOIN playerAttribute AS play ON ' || attr || ' = play.playerId
   WHERE match.matchId = ''' || $1 || ''' AND match.date_match >= play.attribute_date
   ORDER BY play.attribute_date DESC
   LIMIT 1;' INTO temp_row;

   IF counter = 1 THEN
    top_row := temp_row;
   END IF; 

   IF temp_row.rating > top_row.rating THEN
    top_row := temp_row;
   END IF;

  END LOOP;

  RETURN QUERY SELECT player.name AS name, playerAttribute.overall_rating AS rating 
  FROM player
  JOIN playerAttribute ON player.playerId = playerAttribute.playerId
  WHERE player.playerId = top_row.id AND playerAttribute.attribute_date = top_row.date;

 END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The problem is that while executing one single issue of the function is not much of a problem (roughly 2.5/3 ms), it becomes slow if issued for every match in the database (in this case, the waiting time is about 20-30 seconds). 
Do you know a way to optimize the function or the query inside it? (or if you think its pointless trying to improve this one, you can try on suggesting another way of achieving the same result)

EDIT:

Here's the query:

```
SELECT away.player1_id AS id, play.overall_rating AS rating, play.attribute_date AS date
FROM match
JOIN squad AS away ON match.away_squad = away.squadId
JOIN playerAttribute AS play ON away.player1_id = play.playerId
WHERE match.matchId = '400' AND match.date_match >= play.attribute_date
ORDER BY play.attribute_date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

And here's the EXPLAIN:

```
Limit  (cost=18.88..18.88 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.109..0.112 rows=1 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=11
   ->  Sort  (cost=18.88..18.89 rows=4 width=18) (actual time=0.107..0.107 rows=1 loops=1)
         Sort Key: play.attribute_date DESC
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
         Buffers: shared hit=11
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.83..18.86 rows=4 width=18) (actual time=0.057..0.085 rows=5 loops=1)
               Join Filter: (match.date_match >= play.attribute_date)
               Rows Removed by Join Filter: 22
               Buffers: shared hit=11
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.55..16.61 rows=1 width=14) (actual time=0.037..0.039 rows=1 loops=1)
                     Buffers: shared hit=7
                     ->  Index Scan using match_pkey on match  (cost=0.27..8.29 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.022..0.023 rows=1 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: ((matchid)::text = '400'::text)
                           Buffers: shared hit=3
                     ->  Index Scan using squad_pkey on squad away  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=10) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (squadid = match.away_squad)
                           Buffers: shared hit=4
               ->  Index Scan using playerattribute_pkey on playerattribute play  (cost=0.28..2.07 rows=14 width=18) (actual time=0.015..0.032 rows=27 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((playerid)::text = (away.player1_id)::text)
                     Buffers: shared hit=4
 Planning time: 2.029 ms
 Execution time: 0.212 ms
```

EDIT 2:
The tables involved in the query have this structure; first there is the 'match' table

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| matchid | home_team | away_team |     date_match      | etc... |
+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+--------+
|       1 |      9987 |      2807 | 2008-08-17 00:00:00 | ...    |
|       2 |     10000 |      9994 | 2008-08-16 00:00:00 | ...    |
+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+--------+
```

This has to be joined with the relative roster through the 'away_team' column and the 'squadid' attribute on the 'squad' table:

```
+---------+------------+------------+-------+
| squadid | player1_id | player2_id | etc.. |
+---------+------------+------------+-------+
|    2807 |      39890 |      38423 | ...   |
+---------+------------+------------+-------+
```

'squad' has the id and other 11 columns, each for every player id of the roster: and for every playerId we need to join the table 'playerAttribute' which holds many columns, but the one required are these:

```
+----------+---------------------+----------------+--------+
| playerid |   attribute_date    | overall_rating | etc... |
+----------+---------------------+----------------+--------+
|    38423 | 2010-02-22 00:00:00 |             68 | ...    |
+----------+---------------------+----------------+--------+
```

Comment: Can you provide `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the query?

Comment: Why the loop? As far as I can tell this could be replaced with a simple sub-query. `where (player.playerid, playerattributee.attribute_date) in (select ...) `. If you provide some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data it will be a lot easier to come up with a better (single) query.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Here's the output of the EXPLAIN

                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Function Scan on top_away_player  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=36) (actual time=17.160..17.160 rows=1 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=368
 Planning time: 0.055 ms
 Execution time: 17.194 ms

Comment: No, I mean the `EXPLAIN` for the query inside the function. Also, please add it to the question rather than trying to post it as a comment.

Comment: The squad table is a horrible database design. You shouldn't have one column for each player, but one `player_id` and then insert one **row** for each player.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Well, i need a row of some kind that can memorize a whole formation (with 11 players), and it seemed like the most obvious choice, or do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name means: Squad table should contain 2 (perhaps 3) columns: (SquadId, PlayerId) or (SquadId, Player#, PlayerId) where Player# is values 1 - 11. You then just create 11 rows.

Comment: @Belayer the problem is, how can the match row reference the 'squadId'? In this case the 'squadId' column on squad cant be unique

Comment: Sorry @Torres98 is correct, as stated you could not relate any thing to it. What I meant was create as new Squad_Player table. Relate to Squad and to Player tables. Note I assume there are other attributes for both Squad and Player tables.